# Материалы розовые

Tags: unity3d

Я скачал ассет с разными деревьями, а там все модели какого-то странного цвета, а материалы почемуто розовые
Как исправить эту проблему?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Материалы розовые - значит, что на полигонах отсутствуют текстуры. Просто наложите нужные текстуры и все заработает.